# Center of the categories $\mathbf{Grp}$ and $\mathbf{Ab}$.

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, monoid

This is Exercise II.5.8 from Mac Lane, *Categories for the Working Mathematician*.

> For the identity functor $I_C$ of any category, the natural transformations $\alpha:I_C\dot{\to}I_C$ form a commutative monoid. Find this monoid in the cases $C=\mathbf{Grp}$, $\mathbf{Ab}$ and $\mathbf{Set}$.

I found out that this monoid is called the *[center](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/center#OfCategories)* of the category $C$, and I'm going to call is $Z(C)$. My  problem was to find a nice characterization of the centers of $\mathbf{Grp}$ and $\mathbf{Ab}$. Here's my work so far:

Notice that $\alpha:I_C\dot{\to} I_C$ is natural iff $\alpha_c$ commutes with every arrows $f:c\to c$ for every $c$ (in other words, iff $\alpha_c$ is in the center of the monoid $\hom_C(c,c)$). In symbols:
$$Z(C)=\left\{\alpha:I_C\dot{\to}I_C \mid \forall c\in C, \forall f\in\hom_C(c,c), \alpha_c f=f\alpha_c\right\}\qquad (*)$$
This implies directly that the center of $\mathbf{Set}$ is trivial (that is, it contains only the unit natural transformation).

However, this will not work in $\mathbf{Grp}$ and $\mathbf{Ab}$, since the monoid of endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$ is commutative. However, not every two endomorphisms of arbitrary groups commute: Let $G=F_2$, the free group with two generators $a$ and $b$. Let $f,g:F_2\to F_2$ be morphisms such that $f(a)=f(b)=ab$, $g(a)=g(b)=a$. Then $fg(a)=f(a)=ab$, and $gf(a)=g(ab)=a^2$.

That said, the best description of $Z(C)$, for $C=\mathbf{Grp}$ or $\mathbf{Ab}$, I can give at the moment is ($*$) as above. What would be better descriptions of $Z(\mathbf{Grp})$ and $Z(\mathbf{Ab})$?

PS: Since I'm self-studying, I wouldn't tag this question as "homework".

Comment: You will probably like [this blog post](http://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/centers-2-categories-and-the-eckmann-hilton-argument/). It at least answers your question on the centre of $(Ab)=(\mathbb{Z}-Mod.)$.

Comment: It's not correct to say that $\alpha$ is natural iff $\alpha_c$ is in the center of $\hom_C(c,c)$ for all $c$.  That is necessary, but not sufficient in general, because the definition of naturality also requires $\alpha$ to "commute" with maps $f:c\to d$ where $c\neq d$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key idea you're missing is to use *generators* of your category.

In $\mathbf{Set}$, the terminal element generates the category; every map $A \to B$ is completely determined by its composites with maps $\mathbf{1} \to A$ which are a kind of "generalized element", and the fact $\alpha$ is natural lets us understand $\alpha_A$ in terms of $\alpha_\mathbf{1}$.

Writing $a$ for the map $\mathbf{1} \to A$ that sends the unique element of $\mathbf{1}$ to $a \in A$, we have

$$ \begin{matrix} 
\mathbf{1} & \xrightarrow{\alpha_1} & \mathbf{1}
\\ \ \ \downarrow a & & \ \ \downarrow a
\\ A & \xrightarrow{\alpha_A} & A \end{matrix} $$

which implies that $\alpha_A(a) = a$ for all $a \in A$.

The categories $\mathbf{Grp}$ and $\mathbf{Ab}$ are both generated by $\mathbb{Z}$, and the same diagram tells us what we need to know:

$$ \begin{matrix} 
\mathbb{Z} & \xrightarrow{\alpha_\mathbb{Z}} & \mathbb{Z}
\\ \ \ \downarrow x & & \ \ \downarrow x
\\ G & \xrightarrow{\alpha_G} & G \end{matrix} $$

where this time I've written $x$ for the map that sends $1$ to $x \in G$. This tells us

$$ \alpha_G(x) = x^{ \alpha_\mathbb{Z}(1)}$$

so all we need to do is to check which endomorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}$ yield natural transformations when extended to the whole category in this way.

For Abelian groups, for each integer $n$ the operation $x \to x^n$ is indeed a natural transformation, so we see that Z(**Ab**) is the multiplicative monoid of all integers. (in fact, if you consider the additive structure, it is the ring of integers)

For general groups, $x \to x^n$ generally isn't even a group homomorphism. For example, the $n=2$ case would ask for $(xy)^2 = x^2 y^2$, and the $n=-1$ case would ask for $(xy)^{-1} = x^{-1} y^{-1}$, both of which are equivalent to the condition that $x$ and $y$ commute.

Only the cases of $n \in \{ 0, 1 \}$ give group homomorphisms for *every* group, and both are easily seen to be natural transformations. Thus Z(**Grp**) is this two element multiplicative monoid.

Comment: Great answer! I had forgotten to consider morphisms between different objects. So $Z(\mathbf{Grp})$ and $Z(\mathbf{Ab})$ are also trivial, correct?

Comment: @user154803 Actually, $Z(\mathbf{Ab})=\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual multiplication, since by choosing $\alpha_\mathbb{Z}(1)=n$ gives morphisms $\alpha_G(x)=x^n$, natural in $G$.