# How do I determine all the endomorphisms of the identity functor $\text{id}_{\text {Grp} }: \text {Grp}\rightarrow \text {Grp}$?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, functors

I am trying to determine all the endomorphisms of the identity functor $\text{id}_{\text {Grp} }: \text {Grp}\rightarrow \text {Grp}$

I know :

-that the forgetful functor  $F:\text {Grp}\rightarrow \text {Set}$ is representable

-The representing object is $\mathbb Z$

-Using the Yoneda lemma:$$\mathrm{Hom}(F,F) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},-),F) \cong F(\mathbb{Z}),$$

**How do I use these facts to arrive to the thesis?**

Comment: @Kovomaka Could you elaborate a bit on how to do it for the forgetful functor as an example at least? I am clueless how to proceed .You seem to imply it's the same for the identity one. My idea is that the identity functor is a particular case of the F, because every group is a set, so the representing object should be the same and the Yoneda lemma should yield me  the same result (?). But I don't know in either case how to proceed.

Comment: Off the top of my head, maybe you use the fact that from an endomorphism $\alpha : \operatorname{id}_{\mathsf{Grp}} \to \operatorname{id}_{\mathsf{Grp}}$ you can get $F \circ \alpha : F \to F$?  (And then, from the fact that $F$ is faithful, you should be able to show that this function of sets $\operatorname{End}(\operatorname{id}_{\mathsf{Grp}}) \to \operatorname{End}(F)$ is injective.  Though to go further and find the actual endofunctors, you would need to use something like the analysis in mrtaurho's answer anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

Note that the Yoneda Lemma only applies when talking about $\rm Set$-valued functors. However, the identity functor on $\rm Grp$ is evidently not $\rm Set $-valued.

In this particular case, a careful analysis of the objects involved yields the result in an elementary way. We start by unpacking what an endomorphism of the identity functor $\operatorname{id}_{\rm Grp}\colon{\rm Grp}\to{\rm Grp}$ actually is. By definition, this is a collection
$$
(\alpha_G\colon G\to G)_{G\in{\rm Grp}}
$$
of group homomorphisms. Among these groups is the group $G=\mathbb Z$. This group has two important properties:

- $\operatorname{Hom}_{\rm Grp}(\mathbb Z,\mathbb Z)\cong\mathbb Z$ via $(\varphi\colon\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z)\mapsto\varphi(1)$
- $\operatorname{Hom}_{\rm Grp}(\mathbb Z,G)\cong\operatorname{Hom}_{\rm Set}(\{\bullet\},G)$ via $(f\colon\mathbb Z\to G)\mapsto(\{\bullet\}\to UG,\,\bullet\mapsto\varphi(1))$, i.e. group homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z$ into $G$ are in one-to-one correspondence with elements of $g$ (this is representability of the forgetful functor written slightly differently)

This shows immediately, that there are $n$ distinct choices for the map $\alpha_{\mathbb Z}$, uniquely determined by the image of $1$. Fix now one such $n$, i.e. suppose that $\alpha_{\mathbb Z}(1)=n$. If we now let $g\in G$, we can consider the unique group homomorphism $\varphi_g\colon\mathbb Z\to G$ mapping $1$ to $g$. The associated naturality square reads
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\mathbb Z @>{\alpha_{\mathbb Z}}>> \mathbb Z
\\
@V{\varphi_G}VV @VV{\varphi_G}V
\\
G @>>{\alpha_G}> G
\end{CD}
and we deduce that
$$
\alpha_G(g)
=\alpha_G(\varphi_G(1))
=\varphi_G(\alpha_{\mathbb Z}(1))
=\varphi_G(n)
=g^n\,.
$$
Thus, if we fix $n\in\mathbb Z$ so that $\alpha_{\mathbb Z}(1)=n$, then all $\alpha_G\colon G\to G$ are uniquely determined as $g\mapsto g^n$. However, letting $G=F_2$ be the free group in two generators, shows that only $n=0,1$ produce group homomorphisms.

Thus, there are exactly two endomorphisms of the identity functor, one with all components the trivial group homomorphism and one with all components identities.

In the same way one can classify endomorphisms of $\operatorname{id}_{\rm Set}\colon{\rm Set}\to{\rm Set}$ or $\operatorname{id}_{{\rm Mod}_R}\colon{\rm Mod}_R\to{\rm Mod_R}$ for a commutative unital ring $R$. These and your example are computations of the *center* of a category (see also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818624/center-of-the-categories-mathbfgrp-and-mathbfab)).

Comment: I think I've seen versions of Yoneda's lemma for functors on an enriched category.  Although of course, that would still be useless for this case since the category of groups is not enriched over itself.

Comment: In the book I am reading we consider  locally small categories, does that make the functor set-valued?

Comment: And on the other hand a group is a set, does that make it set-valued?

Comment: @darkside By "${\rm Set}$-valued functor" I mean a functor with codomain the category of sets. For a locally small category - such as ${\rm Grp}$ - the functors $\operatorname{Hom}_{\rm Grp}(G,-)$ and $\operatorname{Hom}_{\rm Grp}(-,G)$ are then such functors. However, this does not change the fact, that the identity functor on ${\rm Grp}$ is a functor with codomain ${\rm Grp}$, not ${\rm Set}$. What you essentially describe is the *composition* of the identity functor with the forgetful functor. It is very important in category theory to keep track of how things are defined!

Comment: @DanielSchepler Ah, I see. I was only thinking of the "usual" Yoneda Lemma, i.e. the one for locally small categories found in most introductory texts.

Comment: Could ypu please explain which are the endomorphisms of F:Grp $\rightarrow$ Set? Yoneda yields $\mathrm{Hom}(F,F) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},-),F) \cong F(\mathbb{Z})$, but this only tells me that the endomorphisms are in one to one correspondance with the integers, but who are the endomorphisms actually?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Yoneda lemma just fine here, it just takes an extra step. An endomorphism of the identity functor $\text{Grp} \to \text{Grp}$ is a compatible collection of endomorphisms of every group, whereas an endomorphism of the forgetful functor $\text{Grp} \to \text{Set}$ is a compatible collection of endo*functions* of every group; in particular the former is a *subset* of the latter, so we can start with endomorphisms of the forgetful functor and then examine which ones also give group endomorphisms.

By the Yoneda lemma, endomorphisms of the forgetful functor correspond to endomorphisms of the representing object $\text{End}(\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. This says that the natural endofunctions on groups all take the form

$$G \ni g \mapsto g^n \in G$$

where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now the additional question we need to answer is: for what values of $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is $g \mapsto g^n$ always a group homomorphism?

Note that if we were dealing with abelian groups then the answer is all of them, but because of the existence of nonabelian groups, here the answer is that only $n = 0, 1$ work.

Comment: Another way to make the naïve approach via Yoneda is to recognize the functor category $\textbf{Grp}\to\textbf{Grp}$ as equivalent to the category of group objects in the functor category $\textbf{Grp}\to\textbf{Set}$ (with respect to the pointwise Cartesian monoidal structure of the latter). From the perspective, $1_{\textbf{Grp}}$ is corepresented by a certain *co*group object in $\textbf{Grp}$ with comultiplication map of type $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}$ sending the generator of the former to the product of the generators of the latter.

Comment: Could ypu please explain which are the endomorphisms of F:Grp →
 Set? Yoneda yields $Hom(F,F)≅Hom(Hom(Z,−),F)≅F(Z)$
, but this only tells me that the endomorphisms are in one to one correspondance with the integers, but which are the endomorphisms actually?

Comment: @darkside: you need to apply the definition of $F$ again. $F(Z) \cong \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$, and moreover if you trace out what the actual induced bijection $\text{Hom}(F, F) \cong \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ is, it is given by precomposition. So the integer $n \in \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Z})$ corresponds to precomposing with multiplication by $n$ on $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}, G) \cong G$ and this produces the map $g \mapsto g^n$ as above.